# Java - How to delay after clicking a button

Tags: swing, jbutton, sleep

I have a homework assignment to make a game of concentration.  The only thing I can't figure out is delaying flipping back the cards after the second card is clicked (just the delay part).  I have it so that on click, it shows the card, if it isn't a match, it should delay, then hide the card.  If I use Thread.sleep after it should show the card, it just sleeps before that and never actually shows it.

Is there a way to do this with Thread.sleep or do I have to use timers?  I didn't try hard yet, but I wasn't able to get the timers working right because it should stop allowing input until the delay is over and the cards are flipped back.

Edit: Never mind, I just used timers and checked if it was running already before doing anything.